# How do I skip Helgen?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any way to skip the Helgen prologue on consoles?

It's boring. Sure, I can exploit a glitch during it to level up faster but I'd rather get to the open world faster.

Comment: @JoshPetrie The other question is asking about the cutscene in the cart. This one's asking about the whole Helgen tutorial.

Comment: Not on Consoles, sorry to say.

Comment: @Studoku is right. These questions are not duplicates.  This question is asking about the opening tutorial, whereas the proposed duplicate is only asking how to skip the opening cutscene.

Answer (score 0):

Many others understand how you feel, OP. You can download a mod for Skyrim that addresses this issue exactly, called "Live Another Life." http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/9557/?

As a bonus, it also includes alternate starts which give you different equipment and start you at different places around Skyrim, which is quite nice if you want to role play a little bit.

Comment: The question is actually asking about it on Console, not PC so mods are not going to be an option there.

Comment: My goodness, I completely missed that "on consoles" part. My apologies. Well, at least PC players will know now, if they read this thread.